# How to depth first print a B+Tree C++?

Tags: c++

I have an Order 5 Btree with methods for insert, height, find and print. I am having difficulty understanding how to print depth first A-Z?  I have a print function will show each node and the elements in it but would like to understand how to print in order.  I  prefer the AVL tree for ease.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


const int MAX = 4 ; //maximum # of keys
const int MIN = 2 ; //minimum # of keys

struct btnode  
{
    int count ;
    string value[MAX + 1] ;  //number of elements + 1;
    btnode *child[MAX + 1] ;
} ;

class btree   
{
    private :
        btnode *root ;
    public :
        btree( ) ;
        void insert ( string val ) ;
        int setValue ( string val, btnode *n, string *p, btnode **c ) ;
        static int searchNode ( string val, btnode *n, int *pos ) ;
        void fillNode ( string val, btnode *c, btnode *n, int k ) ;
        void split ( string val, btnode *c, btnode *n, int k, string *y, btnode **newnode ) ;
        void show( ) ;
        //void search(string key);
        int searchPos(string key,string *key_arr,int n);  //sub-function for search
        static void display ( btnode *root) ;
       // void height(string key);
} ;


btree :: btree( )
{
    root = NULL ;
}

int btree :: searchNode ( string val, btnode *n, int *pos )  //searches for string in node
{
    if ( val < n -> value[1] )
    {
        *pos = 0 ;
        return 0 ;
    }
    else
    {
        *pos = n -> count ;
        while ( ( val < n -> value[*pos] ) && *pos > 1 )
            ( *pos )-- ;
        if ( val == n -> value[*pos] )      //if value exists in the node returns 
        {    
            for(int j =0; j <= n->count; j++)
            {
                //cout<<"Test in searchmode function"<<endl;
                cout<<n->value[j]<<endl;
            }
        return 1 ;
        }   

        else
            return 0 ;
    }
}

void btree :: insert ( string val )  //inputting a string
{
    string in ;
    btnode *c, *n ;
    int flag ;
    flag = setValue ( val, root, &in, &c );  //in flag has value

    if ( flag )
    {
        n = new btnode ;            //create a new btnode
        n -> count = 1 ;            //initiates the count to 1
        n -> value[1] = in ;        //value of our node is set to the String passed in
        n -> child[0] = root ;      //setting pointer of child[0] to root
        n -> child[1] = c ;         
        root = n ;
    }
}
int btree :: setValue ( string val, btnode *n, string *p, btnode **ch )    //returns  1 or 0 to set flag
{
    int key ;

    if ( n == NULL )
    {
        *p = val ;
        *ch = NULL ;
        return 1 ;      //if root is NULL 1 is returned to flag and node is created
    }
    else
    {
        if ( searchNode ( val, n, &key ) )  //checks if the value has already been entered
            cout << endl << "Key value already exists." << endl ;

        if ( setValue ( val, n -> child[key], p, ch ) )  
        {
            if ( n -> count < MAX )   //if the node is less than MAX order the node is filled
            {
                fillNode ( *p, *ch, n, key ) ;      
                return 0 ;          //value is returned as 0 to flag    
            }
            else                    //if the MAX for node is met split
            {
                split ( *p, *ch, n, key, p, ch ) ;
                return 1 ;          //after split 1 is returned to flag to set node value
            }
        }
        return 0 ;
    }
}

void btree :: fillNode ( string val, btnode *c, btnode *n, int k )   //function to fill the node
{
    int i ;
    for ( i = n -> count ; i > k ; i-- )     //first node count is = to 1, k=0
    {
        n -> value[i + 1] = n -> value[i] ; 
        n -> child[i + 1] = n -> child[i] ;
    }
    n -> value[k + 1] = val ;       //assigns string to location in node
    n -> child[k + 1] = c ;         //assigns pointer to child
    n -> count++ ;                  //increments node count by one

}

void btree :: split ( string val, btnode *c, btnode *n,
        int k, string *y, btnode **newnode )
{
    int i, mid ;
    cout<<"In split function k is :"<<k;
    if ( k <= MIN )     
        mid = MIN ;     //Min is defined as 2, the minimum number in a node
    else
        mid = MIN + 1 ; //k passing as 3 or 4 will make the midpoint 3

    *newnode = new btnode ;

    for ( i = mid + 1 ; i <= MAX ; i++ )
    {
        ( *newnode ) -> value[i - mid] = n -> value[i] ;  //new node value is placed at i - mid point setting it as first position in split node
        ( *newnode ) -> child[i - mid] = n -> child[i] ;
    }

    ( *newnode ) -> count = MAX - mid ;
    n -> count = mid ;

    if ( k <= MIN )
        fillNode ( val, c, n, k ) ;
    else
        fillNode ( val, c, *newnode, k - mid ) ;  //fillNode is called and *newnode

    *y = n -> value[n -> count] ;                           //mid point moves up to root node
    ( *newnode ) -> child[0] = n -> child[n -> count] ;   
    n -> count-- ;
}


void btree :: show( )
{
    display ( root ) ;
}


void btree :: display ( btnode *root)  
{

    int i=0;
    if ( root != NULL )
    {

        for ( i = 0 ; i < root -> count ; i++ )
        {
               cout<< root->value[i]  ;
           display ( root -> child[i] ) ;

        }
       display ( root-> child[i] ) ;
        //cout<< root->value[i]  ;
    }



}

int main( )
{
    btree b ;
    int choice;
    string key;
    string t = "temp"; //to run through height function.
    do{
    cout<<"\n\n\tSELECT YOUR CHOICE\n\n1. insert\n2. search\n3. display\n4. height\n\n5. EXIT\n\n\n=";
    cin>>choice;
    switch(choice)
    {
                  case 1:cout<<"\n\nEnter the string to be inserted:";
                         cin>>key;
                         b.insert(key);
                         break;
                  case 2:cout<<"\n\nEnter search:";
                          cin>>key;
                         // b.search(key);
                          break;
                  case 3:
                    cout<<"could not get to print A-Z?!." <<endl;
                       b.show();
                       cout<<"\n";
                         break;
                    case 4:

                       //b.height(t);
                       cout<<"\n";
                         break;      

                 case 5:break;
                   default:cout<<"\nINVALID ENTRY";
                           break;};
                           }while(choice!=5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it seems like the display method already shows the results in-order. first shows the left, then mid, then right.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your particular problems with the code you have posted please?

Comment: It only ever displays 4 items, example. I enter a b c d ; it only outputs a b c.

When i then insert e and the node splits, output = a d

Comment: If i use cout after for loop. input = a b c d e output = a b d e c ; c is the mid-point of split that moved up tree and is printed last? Head scratch.

Comment: You shouldn't use anything after the loop. You're done. The loop does it all. Your present code redisplays `child[0]` for some reason, which is futile.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided your `insert()` code and your `main()` function which does the insertions, so we can see what you're doing, rather than (a) having to guess and (b) write the code for ourselves.  See the guidelines on how to write an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  We don't need the `find` or `height` methods, and I assume the 'print' method referred to is the `btnode::display()` method shown in the question.  I'm curious about how the `btnode::display()` function gets its qualified name — is it in `namespace btnode`?

Comment: Code Edit, removes search and find functions.  Simple main function to add strings to tree. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I debug code is by (a) making it non-interactive so I can run the test easily, and (b) by adding printing functions and statements.  I removed the 'UI' code from `main()` and replaced it with hard-coded stuff.

Part of your problem is the `insert()` function; it probably doesn't do what you think it does.  In particular, it places the first value in an empty tree into `value[1]`, not `value[0]`.  I've kludged the code around this issue; it sort of works up until you need to split a node.  At that point, it seems to lose some of the data.

Have fun dealing with that.

You should review passing strings as references versus as values; I've fixed some but by no means all of those.  I didn't find where you needed `<stdlib.h>`; I did add `<cassert>` and some assertions, but I wasn't getting assertions firing.

#### Instrumented code

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int MAX = 4;
const int MIN = 2;

struct btnode
{
    int count;
    string value[MAX + 1];
    btnode *child[MAX + 1];
    void dump(ostream &out, const string &tag);
};

void btnode::dump(ostream &out, const string &tag)
{
    out << "-->> " << tag << ":\n";
    out << "Count:   " << count << "\n";
    assert(value[0] == "");
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        out << "Value " << i << " = <<" << value[i] << ">>\n";
    out << "<<-- " << tag << "\n";
}

class btree
{
    private:
        btnode *root;
    public:
        btree() : root(0) {}
        void insert(const string &val);
        int setValue(const string &val, btnode *n, string *p, btnode **c);
        void fillNode(string val, btnode *c, btnode *n, int k);
        void split(string val, btnode *c, btnode *n, int k, string *y, btnode **newnode);
        void show();
        int searchPos(string key,string *key_arr,int n);
        static void display(btnode *root);
        static int searchNode(const string &val, btnode *n, int *pos);
};

int btree::searchNode(const string &val, btnode *n, int *pos)
{
    if (val < n->value[1])
    {
        *pos = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        *pos = n->count;
        while ((val < n->value[*pos]) && *pos > 1)
            (*pos)--;
        if (val == n->value[*pos])
        {
            for(int j =0; j <= n->count; j++)
            {
                cout << n->value[j] << endl;
            }
            return 1;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
}

void btree::insert(const string &val)
{
    cout << "-->> btree::insert('" << val << "')\n";
    string in = "";
    btnode *c = 0;
    int flag = setValue(val, root, &in, &c);
    cout << "setValue set flag = " << flag << "\n";

    if (flag)
    {
        cout << "Creating new node\n";
        btnode *n = new btnode;
        assert(n != 0);
        n->count = 1;
        n->value[0] = "";
        n->value[1] = in;
        n->child[0] = root;
        n->child[1] = c;
        n->dump(cout, "New node");
        root = n;
        this->show();
    }
    cout << "<<-- btree::insert()\n";
}

int btree::setValue(const string &val, btnode *n, string *p, btnode **ch)
{
    cout << "-->> setValue: <<" << val << ">>\n";
    if (n == NULL)
    {
        *p = val;
        *ch = NULL;
        cout << "<<-- setValue: 1A\n";
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int key;
        if (searchNode(val, n, &key))
            cout << endl << "Key value already exists." << endl;

        if (setValue(val, n->child[key], p, ch))
        {
            if (n->count < MAX)
            {
                fillNode(*p, *ch, n, key);
                cout << "<<-- setValue: 0A\n";
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                split(*p, *ch, n, key, p, ch);
                cout << "<<-- setValue: 1B\n";
                return 1;
            }
        }
        cout << "<<-- setValue: 0B\n";
        return 0;
    }
}

void btree::fillNode(string val, btnode *c, btnode *n, int k)
{
    for (int i = n->count; i > k; i--)
    {
        n->value[i + 1] = n->value[i];
        n->child[i + 1] = n->child[i];
    }
    n->value[k + 1] = val;
    n->child[k + 1] = c;
    n->count++;
}

void btree::split(string val, btnode *c, btnode *n,
        int k, string *y, btnode **newnode)
{
    int i, mid;
    cout << "In split function k is: " << k << "\n";
    if (k <= MIN)
        mid = MIN;
    else
        mid = MIN + 1;

    *newnode = new btnode;

    for (i = mid + 1; i <= MAX; i++)
    {
        (*newnode)->value[i - mid] = n->value[i];
        (*newnode)->child[i - mid] = n->child[i];
    }

    (*newnode)->count = MAX - mid;
    n->count = mid;

    if (k <= MIN)
        fillNode(val, c, n, k);
    else
        fillNode(val, c, *newnode, k - mid);

    *y = n->value[n->count];
    (*newnode)->child[0] = n->child[n->count];
    n->count--;
}

void btree::show()
{
    cout << "-->> show():\n";
    display(root);
    cout << "<<-- show()\n";
}

void btree::display(btnode *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        cout << "Root is not null\n";
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i <= root->count; i++)
        {
            cout << "Value " << i << " = <<" << root->value[i] << ">>\n";
            if (root->child[i-1])
                display(root->child[i-1]);
        }
        if (root->child[i])
            display(root->child[i]);
    }
    else
        cout << "Root is null\n";
}

int main()
{
    btree b;

    string key = "amaranthine";
    b.insert(key);
    b.show();

    key = "absinthe";
    b.insert(key);
    b.show();

    key = "amazonia";
    b.insert(key);
    b.show();

    key = "zululand";
    b.insert(key);
    b.show();

    key = "asbestos";
    b.insert(key);
    b.show();

    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample output

```
-->> btree::insert('amaranthine')
-->> setValue: <<amaranthine>>
<<-- setValue: 1A
setValue set flag = 1
Creating new node
-->> New node:
Count:   1
Value 1 = <<amaranthine>>
<<-- New node
-->> show():
Root is not null
Value 1 = <<amaranthine>>
<<-- show()
<<-- btree::insert()
-->> show():
Root is not null
Value 1 = <<amaranthine>>
<<-- show()
-->> btree::insert('absinthe')
-->> setValue: <<absinthe>>
-->> setValue: <<absinthe>>
<<-- setValue: 1A
<<-- setValue: 0A
setValue set flag = 0
<<-- btree::insert()
-->> show():
Root is not null
Value 1 = <<absinthe>>
Value 2 = <<amaranthine>>
<<-- show()
-->> btree::insert('amazonia')
-->> setValue: <<amazonia>>
-->> setValue: <<amazonia>>
<<-- setValue: 1A
<<-- setValue: 0A
setValue set flag = 0
<<-- btree::insert()
-->> show():
Root is not null
Value 1 = <<absinthe>>
Value 2 = <<amaranthine>>
Value 3 = <<amazonia>>
<<-- show()
-->> btree::insert('zululand')
-->> setValue: <<zululand>>
-->> setValue: <<zululand>>
<<-- setValue: 1A
<<-- setValue: 0A
setValue set flag = 0
<<-- btree::insert()
-->> show():
Root is not null
Value 1 = <<absinthe>>
Value 2 = <<amaranthine>>
Value 3 = <<amazonia>>
Value 4 = <<zululand>>
<<-- show()
-->> btree::insert('asbestos')
-->> setValue: <<asbestos>>
-->> setValue: <<asbestos>>
<<-- setValue: 1A
In split function k is: 3
<<-- setValue: 1B
setValue set flag = 1
Creating new node
-->> New node:
Count:   1
Value 1 = <<amazonia>>
<<-- New node
-->> show():
Root is not null
Value 1 = <<amazonia>>
Root is not null
Value 1 = <<absinthe>>
Value 2 = <<amaranthine>>
<<-- show()
<<-- btree::insert()
-->> show():
Root is not null
Value 1 = <<amazonia>>
Root is not null
Value 1 = <<absinthe>>
Value 2 = <<amaranthine>>
<<-- show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your time looking into this.  It gives me a place to start toward fixing.  Much appretiated!

Answer (score 0):

```
void btree :: display ( btnode *root)  
{
    int i=0;
    if ( root != NULL )
    {
        for ( i = 0 ; i < root -> count ; i++ )
        {
               cout<< root->value[i]  ;
           display ( root -> child[i] ) ;

        }
```

So far so good.

```
       display ( root-> child[i] ) ;
        //cout<< root->value[i]  ;
```

Just remove this. It is displaying root->child[0] again. You've already done that.

```
    }
}
```

Comment: When I remove display (root->child[i]) and the cout this function and enter the letters a - z and run display function my out put is:

acdijlm  When I draw out the tree and its splits the function is only printing items at [1] in the left side of tree and ignoring the right side of the tree altogether?

Comment: The line outside the loop is displaying `root->child[root->count]` because the loop stops when `i == root->count`.  Only in the case where `root->count` is zero is it redisplaying the same node again.